# Facebook insights / analytics feed post ref parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook analytics lets you split story distribution based on "ref parameter". However when publishing posts, I [cannot see any mention of how to set this ref parameter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed).

I would assume it would be a ref argument when doing a POST to the feed, but this does not seem to be the case based on the docs. Just to make sure, I tried publishing some feed stories with the ref parameter set, but those did not show up in insights.

How do you set the ref parameter so that it would show up in app insights / analytics?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#learn

> “**Some plugins** also have a `ref` parameter which can be used to track traffic generation on your site. If a friend clicks on a story about someone liking one of your pages, we'll pass the ref parameter back to your site, where you can track it with your own analytics software. See the parameters for [social plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins) for more info.”

Highlight by me – AFAIK it doesn’t say *anywhere* in the docs, that you could set this as an API parameter yourself when making posts via API.

> Just to make sure, I tried publishing some feed stories with the ref parameter set, but those did not show up in insights.

You mean, you added `ref` as an additional API parameter in your call that makes the post – or did you append it to the URL that you are posting directly? The latter might or might not work, depending of whether the `og:url` value contains the parameter as well. (But be aware that if you include different `rev` parameter values into the `og:url`, Facebook will treat them as different URLs/Open Graph objects – so likes, shares etc. will be *split* between them, counted individually for each of them. Whether that’s a “wanted” or at least acceptable side-effect, is for you to decide. And anyway, no guarantee this’ll work at all.)

Comment: Thanks, I agree that it says nowhere in the docs that ref can be passed. However the insights interface lets you sort feed posts by the ref parameter,  which is strange if there is no way to set it.

Comment: There _is_ a way to set it – when sharing/liking happens via one of the Social Plugins.